# integer to string from database

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

i have stored my values in the database as followes:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + 
        ABezoeAdapter.databasetabel + "(" +
        ABezoeAdapter.recordnummer + " INTEGER, " +
        ABezoeAdapter.bezoekrapportnummer + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        ABezoeAdapter.bezoekrapportdatum + " DATETIME NOT NULL, " +
        ABezoeAdapter.herstellingsoort + " VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, " +
```

but this gives me problems with following reading routine

```
Cursor c = onzedatabase.query(databasetabel, allekolommen, bezoekrapportnummer + "=?", new String[] {bezoeknummer}, null, null, null);

        int i = 0;
        String data[] = new String[30];
        data = null;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            data[i] = c.getString(i);
            Log.i("abezoeadapter gegevenslezenvanbezoeknummer", "bezoeknummer = " + data[2]);
        }
```

out of the logcat i think i get a problem because my values are stored as integer, string, ...

logcat:

```
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity      ComponentInfo{com.example.deceunincktechniekers/com.example.deceunincktechniekers.bezoekrapporten}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.example.deceunincktechniekers.ABezoeAdapter.gegevenslezenvanbezoeknummer(ABezoeAdapter.java:480)
03-24 18:36:06.321: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.example.deceunincktechniekers.bezoekrapporten.opslaan(bezoekrapporten.java:784)
```

what can be the solution for my different type of values
internet searches didnt helped me out so far

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String data[] = new String[30];
data = null;
```

You assign `data` to `null` and then try to assign values to it. Hence the NPE. Remove the `data = null`.

To deal with variable number of entries, consider using e.g. an `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String[]`.